# Can't move svg element in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Cant seem to figure out how to move a D3 map i made - just want to move the map on the page, not resize, etc.

Heres the code-

```
    var width = 700;
    var height = 880;


    //create SVG

    var mapContainer = d3.select("body")
        .append("mapContainer")
        .attr( "width", 900 )
        .attr ( "height", 900 )



    var Map = mapContainer.append(svg)
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr( "width", width )
        .attr ( "height", height )
        var g = svg.append ( "g" )


    //GeoPath
    var geoPath = d3.geoPath()
        .projection( albersProjection );

    g.selectAll( "path" )
        .data( Chicago.geometries )
        .enter()
        .append( "path" )
        .attr( "stroke", "white" )
        .attr( "border-radius", '50%' )
        .attr( "stroke-width", ".5" )
        .attr( "fill", "#black" )
        .attr( "opacity", ".2" )
        .attr("class","communities")
        .attr( "d", geoPath )




    //lets load crimes
    // svg repositioning

    var crimes = svg.append( "g" );

    rodents.selectAll( "path" )
        .data( homicides.features )
        .enter()
        .append( "path" )
        .attr( "pointRadius", "10px" )
        .attr( "fill", initialDate)
        .attr( "stroke", "#ccc" )
        .attr("opacity", 1)
        .attr( "d", geoPath.pointRadius(initialDateMatchRadius) )
        .attr("class","incident")
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            d3.select("h2").text(d.properties.Block);
            d3.select(this).attr("class","hover");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){
            d3.select("h2").text("");
            d3.select(this).attr("class","incident");
        });
```

When I inspect the live page, the 'g' element seems to be the container holding my map.  When I try to add a line under my existing code like:

```
var Map = mapContainer.append(svg)
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr( "width", width )
    .attr ( "height", height )
    // Trying to move g element
    var g = svg.append ( "g" )
       .attr('cx', 40)
```

Nothing happens.  Setting the position attribute in the same manner doesnt work either.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `cx` attribute positions the center of  a circle but won't have any effect on a `g`, instead you could apply a transform on the `g`, try `svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(40,0)")`

Comment: Why do you need to move the map on the page? Do you need to set up your map with margins?

Comment: ksav, probably .  How would I do that?